# Failed to read list chunk using mmio function?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7, wav

This is part of my code for reading a .wav file

```
    //Variable
    wavehdr:TWaveHeader;
    ckiRIFF,ckiFmt,ckiData,ckiLIST: TMMCKInfo;
    mmioinfo: PMMIOInfo;
    waveFmt: TWaveFormatEx;
    buf: Array of smallint;
    buf_recon: Array of double;
    list:Array of longint; // THIS IS MY GUESS so it's definetly not work
    HMMIO: hFile;

    //Locate the "RIFF" chunk
    ckiRIFF.fccType := mmioStringToFOURCC('WAVE',0);
    mmioDescend(HMMIO, @ckiRIFF, nil, MMIO_FINDRIFF);
    mmioAscend(HMMIO, @ckiRIFF, MMIO_FINDRIFF);

    //Locate the "FMT" subchunk
    ckiFmt.ckid := mmioStringToFOURCC('fmt', 0);
    mmioDescend(HMMIO, @ckiFmt, nil, MMIO_FINDCHUNK);
    mmioRead(HMMIO, @waveFmt, ckiFmt.cksize);
    mmioAscend(HMMIO, @ckiFmt, 0);

    //Locate the "LIST" chunk (THIS PART IS NOT WORK)
    ckiLIST.fccType := mmioStringToFOURCC('LIST',0);
    mmioDescend(HMMIO, @ckiLIST, nil, MMIO_FINDLIST);
    mmioRead(HMMIO, @list, ckiLIST.cksize);
    mmioAscend(HMMIO, @ckiFmt, 0);

    //Locate the "data" subchunk
    ckiData.ckid := mmioStringToFOURCC('data', 0);
    if (mmioDescend(HMMIO, @ckiData, @ckiRIFF, MMIO_FINDCHUNK) = MMSYSERR_NOERROR) then begin
    SetLength(buf, ckiData.cksize);
    mmioRead(HMMIO, PAnsiChar(buf), ckiData.cksize);
```

And it work just perfect until i realized that i missed the LIST chunk, where i only manage to get 'LIST'. Here an example for file before i read and write it back and there is list chunk and it's data [image]

and here is after i read and write it back [image]

the part i marked gone. So if anyone know what my mistake here please help me

EDIT 1

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many problems with your code:

1. You are not checking for errors.
2. You are not allocating any memory for the list before reading it.
3. You are not reading the "LIST" chunk correctly anyway, because there is no "LIST" chunk in WAV files to begin with. What you are trying to read is an "INFO" chunk that is a LIST type.  So you have to find and descend into the "INFO" chunk, descend into and read its sub-chunks as needed, and then ascend back into the RIFF chunk.
4. You are ascending out of the "RIFF" chunk when you should not be.

Try this instead:

```
var
  wavehdr: TWaveHeader;
  ckiRIFF, ckiFmt, ckiData, ckiLIST, ckiINAM: TMMCKInfo;
  mmioinfo: PMMIOInfo;
  waveFmt: TWaveFormatEx;
  buf: Array of smallint;
  buf_recon: Array of double;
  HMMIO: hFile;
begin
  ...
  //Locate the "RIFF" chunk
  ckiRIFF.fccType := mmioStringToFOURCC('WAVE',0);
  if mmioDescend(HMMIO, @ckiRIFF, nil, MMIO_FINDRIFF) = 0 then
  begin
    //Locate the "FMT" subchunk
    ZeroMemory(@waveFmt, SizeOf(waveFmt));
    ckiFmt.ckid := mmioStringToFOURCC('fmt', 0);
    if mmioDescend(HMMIO, @ckiFmt, @ckiRIFF, MMIO_FINDCHUNK) = 0 then
    begin
      // technically, you should use a dynamic-length buffer instead of a static buffer
      mmioRead(HMMIO, @waveFmt, ckiFmt.cksize);
      mmioAscend(HMMIO, @ckiFmt, 0);
    end;

    //Locate the "INFO" chunk
    ckiLIST.fccType := mmioStringToFOURCC('INFO', 0);
    if mmioDescend(HMMIO, @ckiLIST, @ckiRIFF, MMIO_FINDLIST) = 0 then
    begin
      //Locate the "INAM" chunk
      ckiINAM.fccType := mmioStringToFOURCC('INAM', 0);
      if mmioDescend(HMMIO, @ckiINAM, @ckiLIST, MMIO_FINDCHUNK) = 0 then
      begin
        // read chunk data as needed...
        mmioAscend(HMMIO, @ckiINAM, 0);
      end;
      mmioAscend(HMMIO, @ckiLIST, 0);
    end;

    //Locate the "data" subchunk
    ckiData.ckid := mmioStringToFOURCC('data', 0);
    if (mmioDescend(HMMIO, @ckiData, @ckiRIFF, MMIO_FINDCHUNK) = MMSYSERR_NOERROR) then
    begin
      SetLength(buf, ckiData.cksize);
      mmioRead(HMMIO, PAnsiChar(buf), ckiData.cksize);
      mmioAscend(HMMIO, @ckiData, 0);
    end;
    ...
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: i followed your suggestion but the result is like this edit 1

Comment: seems like i missed something, this part // read chunk data as needed... should i use mmioRead(HMMIO, @inam, ckiINAM.cksize); ? and what variable i need to store it ?

Comment: Ok i figure it out thanks to you man. i still digging on it because not all wav file has INAM chunk, moreover some may has more than INAM chunk like the chunk which stored date of the file created etc. You're AWESOME man..